# ASP.NET Core Web API - System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Mandate>()

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In ASP.NET Core-6 Web API Project I have this code:

```
private async Task<int> GetTotalCustomers()
{
    var userName = _currentUserService.UserName;

    var merchantId = _dbContext.Merchants
        .Where(u => u.User.UserName == userName)
        .Select(m => m.Id)
        .FirstOrDefault();

    var customersList = await _dbContext.Mandates
        .Where(x => x.MerchantId == merchantId)
        .GroupBy(x => x.DrAccountNumber)
        .ToListAsync();

    return customersList.Count();
}
```

I got this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .Where(x => x.MerchantId == __merchantId_0)
> .GroupBy(x => x.DrAccountNumber)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.

As stated in the error, already I have `ToListAsync()`

How do I get this resolved?

Thanks

Comment: The error means use `ToListAsync` *before* the `GroupBy`.

Comment: How about `_dbContext.Mandates.Where(...).DistinctBy(x => x.DrAccountNumber).Count()`?

Comment: This is an EF Core and data access problem. If the `Merchant` and `Mandate` entities had proper relations you could write `return _dbContext.Mandates.Count(m=>m.Merchant.User.UserName==userName);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of executing two queries, everything can be written in one query, which will be more effective.

```cs
private Task<int> GetTotalCustomers()
{
    var userName = _currentUserService.UserName;

    var query =
        from m in _dbContext.Merchants.Where(m => m.User.UserName == userName)
        from mandate in _dbContext.Mandates.Where(mandate => mandate.MerchantId == m.Id)
        select x.DrAccountNumber;

    return query.Distinct().CountAsync();
}
```

Comment: Is it advisable to use `Take(1)` (I am genuinely curious)? I have written joins the same way you have above but never used Take(1) even when expecting only a single result from one table.

Comment: We can remove Take if `m.User.UserName` is Unique constraint. Probably it is.

Comment: Why `Take(1)` ? Without an explicit `OrderBy` that essentially returns a random matching merchant. The `FirstOrDefault` in the original query is probably used only to retrieve the ID as an integer, not because there are multiple merchants for the same user

Comment: Removed `Take` probably it has no sense here.